# Javascript executeSql does not do anything

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

I'm running Javascript on my phone via phonegap and I wanted to do a post-request and then store the result in the local SQL database.

The code looks like this

```
database.transaction(function(tx) {
  $.post('url', "", function(data, textStatus) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log("1 " + tx);
      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table");
      console.log("2");
    }
  });
}, errorDB, successDB);
```

log 1 is reached, but log 2 is not, therefore executeSql did not work.

I think it does not work, because a POST request in a database transaction is somehow not allowed, maybe due to timeouts?

OR is there something different that is a problem?

Thank you for your help.

P.S. can't see what error happens, because I can't remote-debug on my phone (somehow it does not work with Samsung Galaxi S3, but I'm working on it) and I can't run my code on my PC, because phonegap.

Comment: Why do you post and if you HAVE to post, why ins't database.transaction inside the return function of the post?

Comment: Where is tx defined?

Comment: @Eric the sql statement would insert data from the post, but i simplified it to prevent errors.

Comment: @Robert Moskal tx is defined in the first row of my code. I checked that it is not undefined.

Comment: is there a callback available for executeSql?  BTW, it's not that hard to run your phonegap app on your pc.

Comment: @Robert Moskal there is a callback function to handle the result (actually two, success and error callback), but that is not relevant in this case I think.